# Batch - Parsing and formatting multiple files depending on content

Tags: windows, batch-file

All my files are located in the same folder and are all txt files
My files look like this:

```
CPSITE=00009041695
UID=W1KRVWHTSNRD,W1KRVULRRGPJ,
W1KRVWMTVNOJ,W1KRQUDTRMLK,W1KRVSHRUHTI,0
```

Or like this:

```
CPSITE=00009041695 
UID=0
```

What I'm looking to achieve is to create a single file with all the id's `W1K....` listed one above the other. Each file can contains between `0` and infinite number of id's *(lets say `1000`)*.

This is what I've been able to make so far:

*First version*

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem parsing all files of the folder
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
set "filename=%%f"
echo Traitement du fichier !filename!
rem for each line of the current file
for /f "delims=" %%a in (!filename!) do (
    SET s=%%a
    rem replace , with ; 
    SET s=!s:,=;!
    remstock line in a new file
    echo !s! >> v2!filename!
)
rem then finally replace old file with new one
mv v2!filename! !filename!
)
```

Using this was my first idea and I just wanted to use a `new line character` to replace the `,` but I've not been able to do it, also this would have caused problems with lines that ends with a "," as it would create a second new line.

*So next approach:*

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem parse file
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set "filename=%%f"
    rem for each file, removing first line as it will never be used
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (!filename!) do (
        SET s=%%a
        rem if there is a coma in the line, the line contains at least one ID
        If NOT "!s!"=="!s:,=!" (
            echo , found in !s!
            rem this is where I struggle, this for what I understand is supposed to print all occurences of string delimited by "," but it only show the first one and then stops
            for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ("!s!") do (
                echo id value: %%a
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I think the best solution here would be to add all the found id's in a new file, going to a new line each time but I am not able to do it.

What I expect to achieve from the examples above:

```
W1KRVWHTSNRD
W1KRVULRRGPJ
W1KRVWMTVNOJ
W1KRQUDTRMLK
W1KRVSHRUHTI
```

Comment: Just use a `for %%b in (!s!) do echo %%b`. The default separators of items in plain `for` command are the space, comma, semicolon and equal-sign...

Comment: And Row ID, I have changed the formatting of your file content, please confirm if the `UID` value should be all on one line as I have edited it, or over more than one as you had it!

Comment: it works perfectly, if you want to make an anwser I'll mark it as the good answer